# Magento script change not appearing

Tags: magento, magento2

I just need to make small change to a javascript file on a magento theme.  I have gone into file on server and made update but the old file is still cached on front end.

In server I have run these commands:

```
php magento cache:clean 

php magento cache:flush

php magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

But it still shows the old javascript file and not the new one I edited.

How do I generate the static file to use new javascript?

Comment: windows or linux?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to delete or rename that file from pub directory
2. Clear browser cache and history
3. Run php magento setup:static-content:deploy command.
4. Clear magento cache.

Hope this would help you.

Answer (score 0):

I set deploy mode to developer and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

First you can go to `var` directory remove `cache` folder

Run below commands:

```
php magento setup:static-content:deploy    
php magento cache:clean    
php magento cache:flush
```

Hope this help for you

Answer (score 0):

For the solution please follow below steps :

1. Go to **pub** folder and rename **static** folder.
2. Go to command prompt and run command for give **755 & 644 permission** to the **pub** folder.
3. Run command : php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Once done above process please check may hope issue will be resolve.